# Accessing In Place Archive of a Shared Mailbox in Office 365?

Tags: office-365, exchange-server

I'm currently working on a way to get access to the content in an in-place archive on a shared mailbox.

We currently have a client who has a former employee's mailbox converted to a shared mailbox. It was previously on an E3 subscription and had an in-place archive enabled but the license was transferred to a new employee. I can still see on the web portal and via PowerShell that the in-place archive is still enabled and present but we are having trouble accessing it online.

Is there any way to access it via OWA or in some other way?

Answer (score 1):

I have done a little bit of reading on this and from what I can find the Online Archiving for Shared Mailboxes is only visible in OWA, it will not show up in Outlook or other clients.

The Shared Mailbox is given a 50gb Online Archive, after that it requires an Exchange Online Archiving license (or equivalent e2 or e3 license).